# How does one pass a Vec<T> to a function when the trait Seek is required?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have an API that I need to pass a `Vec<u8>` to that requires its parameter to implement `std::io::Seek`:

```
fn some_func<T: Seek + Write>(foo: &mut T) {/* body */}
```

The crate author suggests using a `File` here, however I want to avoid using that here as it would result in unneeded file creation. A `Vec<u8>` satisfies the `Write` trait, but not the `Seek` trait. Is there any way to avoid using a `File` here?

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the `Vec<u8>` in a [`std::io::Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html):

```
let mut buf: Cursor<Vec<u8>> = Cursor::new(Vec::new());
some_func(&mut buf);
```